# Organic Groups let users with a particular role Edit/Delete content only in the group(s) they belong to

Tags: organic-groups, users

I am using Organic Groups and have a custom role say "A". I want users with "A" role to be able to "edit/delete" any content only in the groups they belong to.

I have tried setting up with base System and OG permissions and also using Field Permissions, OG Role Override modules, but can't get exactly what i want.

Any direction on this is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mark a content type as og group and the rest as og group audience

Comment: I use OG 7.x - 2.7.  In my case the content types being created are already "Group Content" they can not be "Groups". What i want is: for example i have 4 users with role "A" which are members of "Some OG group 1". These 4 users should be able to edit/delete any content that is posted in "Some OG group 1", but they should have rights just to view any content posted in "Some OG group 2". Thanks

Comment: I m not sure how OG Role Override module affects your site. However you can create a content type (e.g. Group) that is an og group. Then create two or more nodes of this type (e.g. Some OG group 1, Some OG Group 2). Next add users to each of those groups.

Then you have to mark your other content types as group content. A field (group audience) will appear on their node creation form. If you select Group 1 as the group audience for a node marked as group content.

Comment: You can use custom code to autopopulate the Group Audience field if this is what you need too.

Comment: Thanks Nikos, I already have the setup that you mention above, but my users with "A" role can still edit content that belongs to a group that they are not member of.

Comment: Be sure to check other modules that implement Node access rights (e.g. worflow, or a custom module implementing hook_node_access) https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/group/node_access/7
If another module grants permissions down the chain then it may override the settings of og
Sometimes rebuilding permissions helps if something went wrong during development

Comment: It was the role assignment inside each group that i was missing. After that everything worked fine.